# save as a csv file using vb6

Tags: listview, vb6

below is my code to parse a text file data.. the next thing that i need to do is to execute it as a csv file.. what is the code for saving a text file to a csv file type? thank you in advance for the help.

```
Private Sub cmd_parse_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim ff As Integer
Dim sText As String


Dim myFSO, ts, ts2, ft2, ft1, r
Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = myFSO.GetFile(txtfilename.Text)
Set ft1 = ts.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
List1.AddItem Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") & " Time start"


Do Until ft1.AtEndOfStream
    a = ft1.ReadLine
    r = r + 1
    Text1.Text = r
    a = Split(a, ",")

        For i = 0 To UBound(a)
            Text2.Text = a(i)
            If Text2.Text = "Date Time" Then
                    ListView1.ListItems.Add(1).Text = Text2.Text
                End If

                If Text2.Text = "Date Time" Then
                    Text2.Text = ""
                End If
                If Text2.Text = a(1) Then
                    ListView2.ListItems.Add(1).Text = a(1)
                    GoTo 1
                End If
                If Not IsNumeric(Text2.Text) Then
                    ListView1.ListItems.Add(1).Text = a(i)
                Else
                ListView2.ListItems.Add(1).Text = a(i)
                   ' Stop
            End If
1

        Next i
    DoEvents
Loop
List1.AddItem Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") & " Time end"

txtfilename.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: to save data as a csv file you simple add all the data separatred by comma's before you save it to the file ... the file is a plain text file .. give the filename as extension .csv to make clear that it is a csv file

Comment: can you give me a sample code for that?

Answer (score 1):

what is your example code supposed to do?

some comments:

you define some variables without types, this will make them a variant .. it is always better to declare variables as a specific type

```
Dim myFSO, ts, ts2, ft2, ft1, r
```

it first reads in a file and stores each line in a variable 
it then splits the linedata over each comma, so i assume it reads in a csv file?
you are using the same variable to store the complete line, as well as to store the array holding each item ... i never tried it and am suprised if this works .. but you should definetly use one variable to hold the complete string and another variable to hold the array

```
a = ft1.ReadLine
r = r + 1
Text1.Text = r
a = Split(a, ",")
```

you can declare and array as follows:

```
dim strArray() as string
```

and your split command might then be:

```
strArray = Split(a, ",")
```

you then loop over each item of the csv and perform some actions:

you store the csv item in a textbox .. why? you already have it as a(i) .. copying it to the textbox just slows the process

you then check if the item is "Date Time" and if thats true then you add that to the listbox

```
      If Text2.Text = "Date Time" Then
        ListView1.ListItems.Add(1).Text = Text2.Text
      End If
```

next you check again if the item is "Date Time" and if thats true then you empty the textbox ... why dont you do that in the same "if then"  ?

you then check if text2 still contains the same data, which is always so except when the data was "Date Time" ... so why dont you use "else" with your "if then" ... that is what "else" is for

you then check if the data is nummeric, but wether or not it is nummeric you perform the same action ??

```
      If Not IsNumeric(Text2.Text) Then
        ListView1.ListItems.Add(1).Text = a(i)
      Else
        ListView2.ListItems.Add(1).Text = a(i)
        ' Stop
      End If
```

after cleaning up your code in the loop (but still wondering what it does) it might look as follows:

```
    Do Until ft1.AtEndOfStream
      a = ft1.ReadLine
      r = r + 1
      Text1.Text = r
      strArray = Split(a, ",")
      For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)
        If strArray(i) = "Date Time" Then
          ListView1.ListItems.Add(1).Text = strArray(i)
          Text2.Text = ""
        Else
          ListView2.ListItems.Add(1).Text = strArray(i)
          Text2.Text = strArray(i)
          GoTo 1
        End If
        ListView1.ListItems.Add(1).Text = strArray(i)
1
      Next i
      DoEvents
    Loop
```

This is still some weird code as it:

- adds the csv item to the listbox
- adds the csv item to the listbox again (except when the csv item is "Date Time")
- shows the csv item in Text2.Text (except when the csv item is "Date Time") -

btw to write data to a file you can use .WriteLine() : [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)